# Python: Write a program that asks the user for a color, a line width, a line length and a shape

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

> Write a program that asks the user for a color, a line width, a line length and a shape. The shape should be either a line, a triangle, or a square. Use turtle graphics to draw the shape that the user requests of the size, color, line width and line length that the user requests. For example, if these are the user choices for color, width, line length  and shape

what color? blue
what line width? 25
what line length? 100
line, triangle or square? triangle

This is my attempt:

```
color = input('Enter your preferred turtle line color: ') 
width = input('Enter your preferred turtle line width: ')
length = input('Enter your preferred turtle line length: ')
shape = input('Specify whether you want to draw a line, triangle, or square: ')

import turtle
s = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.pencolor(color)
t.pensize(width)
if shape == 'line':
    t.forward(length)

elif shape == 'triangle':
    t.forward(length)
    t.right(45)
    t.forward(length)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(length)

else:
    t.forwad(length)
    t.right(90)
    t.forwad(length)
    t.right(90)
    t.forwad(length)
    t.right(90)
    t.forwad(length)
```

I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#42>", line 4, in <module>
    t.forward(length)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/turtle.py", line 1637, in forward
    self._go(distance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/turtle.py", line 1604, in _go
    ende = self._position + self._orient * distance
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/turtle.py", line 257, in __mul__
    return Vec2D(self[0]*other, self[1]*other)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Can someone please explain why the length in the forward commands won't go through?

Comment: Try to format your question so it's more readable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: I think you rinput variables, .e.g. length are all strings. make them floats or intigers.

Comment: It's python3 Adam, you can see it in the traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I see is that you've left an 'r' out of forward.

```
t.forwad(length)
```

should be

```
t.forward(length)
```

Also, if you use `input()` `width` and `length` will be strings, but they need to be typecast.  [Specifically](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.forward), length needs to be an integer or float and width must be a positive integer.

```
length = None
while not length:
    try:
        length = float(input('Enter your preferred turtle line length: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('You need to enter a number')

width = None
while not width:
    try:
        width = int(input('Enter your preferred turtle line width: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('You need to enter a positive integer')
    else:
        if width < 1:
            print('You need to enter a positive integer')
            width = None
```

The code I have here will use a loop to get the proper input from the user.  It will try to reject bad inputs.  For example, if the user types 'pumpkin' when you are asking for the length.

Similarly, the way I am catching problems with the length and width entries, you'll want to catch problems with user entry for the shape and color.  Make sure the user enters a valid color.  Make sure the shape is in the list of allowable shapes.

The last problem is that your code here is not indented properly.  You need to indent after the `if:` and `else:` clauses.

Here is the whole program working:

```
import turtle

s = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()

length = None
while not length:
    try:
        length = float(input('Enter your preferred turtle line length: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('You need to enter a number')

width = None
while not width:
    try:
        width = int(input('Enter your preferred turtle line width: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('You need to enter a positive integer')
    else:
        if width < 1:
            print('You need to enter a positive integer')
            width = None
color = None
while not color:
    color = input('Enter your preferred turtle line color: ')
    try:
        t.pencolor(color)
    except:
        print('You need to enter a color that I know.')
        color = None
shape = None
while not shape:
    shape = input('Specify whether you want to draw a line, triangle, or square: ')
    if shape.lower() not in ['line', 'triangle', 'square']:
        shape = None
        print('I only draw lines, triangles and squares!')


t.pensize(width)
if shape.lower() == 'line':
    t.forward(length)
elif shape.lower() == 'triangle':
    t.forward(length)
    t.right(120)
    t.forward(length)
    t.right(120)
    t.forward(length)
else:
    t.forward(length)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(length)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(length)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(length)

s.exitonclick()
```

Note that I also fixed the triangles...

Comment: `length` must be an int or a float. `width` must be a "positive number".
https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.forward

Comment: @HåkenLid Interesting, because the traceback seems to show he used a `float` and it's throwing an error.

Comment: I think the problem is the sequence, not the float. `str * float` doesn't work.

Comment: Your shape input testing logic is flawed as it will accept TRIANGLE but then draw a square.

Comment: Good catch, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing command line input with turtle graphics seems a bad idea if the values you want can be obtained using the graphic input methods that the turtle module provides:

- `textinput(title, prompt)`
- `numinput(title, prompt, default=None, minval=None, maxval=None)`

These are designed to prevent some of the errors that command line code needs to trap.  Here's your program rewritten with graphic input methods:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, TurtleGraphicsError

screen = Screen()

length = None
while not length:
    length = screen.numinput('Select Length', 'Enter your desired line length:', minval=1)

width = None
while not width:
     width = screen.numinput('Select Width', 'Enter your desired line width:', minval=1, default=1)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.pensize(width)

color = None
while not color:
    try:
        color = screen.textinput('Select Color', 'Enter your desired line color:')
        turtle.pencolor(color)
    except TurtleGraphicsError:
         color = None

shape = None
while not shape or shape.lower() not in {'line', 'triangle', 'square'}:
    shape = screen.textinput('Select Shape', 'Specify whether you want a line, triangle, or square:')
shape = shape.lower()

if shape == 'line':
    turtle.forward(length)
elif shape == 'triangle':
    for _ in range(3):
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.right(120)
else:
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.right(90)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score -1):

your else conditional has a grammatical error : `t.forwad(length)` instead of `t.forward(length)`

Comment: That was an issue, thank you, but I still have the error can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Answer (score -1):

You are using Python 3.x, and `input()` there returns a string, not a float.
You need to cast the result before using it as a number:

```
length = float(input('Enter your preferred line length: '))
```

The problem is that somewhere inside `turtle` class, `length` is multiplied by a floating-point number. If `length` itself would be a number, everything would be ok. But in your case, `length` is a string, so Python has to perform `string * float`. Now, `string` is treated as a sequence of characters. In Python, it is valid to multiply a sequence by integer (`'ab'*3` = `'ababab'`), but not by other types (in particular, by float). That's why you get this error message about multiplying sequence by non-int type.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the error slightly. `__mul__` is complaining that he's doing `[some, sequence] * some_float`. What's `[0, 1, 2] * 1.5`? :)

Comment: `"1.5" * 1.5` also raises the same error: `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

Comment: Right. More precisely, it complains about `self[0]*other`, where `self[0]` is `turtle._orient[0]` and `other` is `length`. I presume that one of them is string (which is a sequence of characters), and it is very likely that the culprit is `length` :)

Answer (score -1):

```
import turtle

s = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()

length = None
while not length:
    try:
        length = float(input('Enter your preferred turtle line length: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('You need to enter a number')

width = None
while not width:
    try:
        width = int(input('Enter your preferred turtle line width: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('You need to enter a positive integer')
    else:
        if width < 1:
            print('You need to enter a positive integer')
            width = None
color = None
while not color:
    color = input('Enter your preferred turtle line color: ')
    try:
        t.pencolor(color)
    except:
        print('You need to enter a color that I know.')
        color = None
shape = None
while not shape:
    shape = input('Specify whether you want to draw a line, triangle, or square: ')
    if shape.lower() not in ['line', 'triangle', 'square']:
        shape = None
        print('I only draw lines, triangles and squares!')strong text
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.